# How to verify the body before sending the request in angular unittest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http-post, karma-jasmine, testbed

I having some trouble in making a unit test, I read a lot of articles, but none of them helped me, seems hard to make a simple test.

I need to test this function, it returns an `Observable`, I actually only need to verify if `myBody` was build correctly, I don't want to make an actual `HttpRequest`.

```js
public myCoolFunction(params) {
    const myBody= new buildMyBodyModel();
    this.buildMyBody(params, myBody); // private function, will set the values for me
    return this.sendService.send(myBody); // make a htppPostRequest and returns to me a Observeble
}
```

```js
private buildMyBody(params, myBody){
    myBody.name = params.name;
    myBody.color = params.customColor;
    myBody.count = params.number + 1;
}
```

Expected `myBody`:

```js
{
    name = 'Jack';
    color = 'Orange';
    count = 4;
}
```

Comment: If you only want to test if the body was build correctly, wouldn't it be sufficient to just test the buildMyBody() function?

Comment: hmm testing private functions is a good pratice?

Comment: Of course, you should test every function in your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking for:-

```
it('send method should be called with expected param', () => {
    const sendService = TestBed.get(SendService);
    const params = { name: 'Jack', customColor: 'Orange', number: 3 };
    spyOn(sendService, 'send');
    component.myCoolFunction(params);
    expect(sendService.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'Jack', color: 'Orange', count: 4 });
});
```

If you only need to test if your myBody is built correctly, try this:-

```
it('buildMyBody should change myBody according to params', () => {
    const myBody= new buildMyBodyModel();
    const params = { name: 'Jack', customColor: 'Orange', number: 3 };
    (component as any).buildMyBody(params, myBody);
    expect(myBody).toEqual({ name: 'Jack', color: 'Orange', count: 4 });
});
```